# if loop in bash not being evaluated

Tags: string, bash, if-statement

I am trying to traverse into a set of directories, read a line from a file, parse it to assign the value of a variable, and then act if the variable matches a predefined string. I am running it using "#!/bin/bash. Here is the code.

```
23 for DIR in $(find . -name "H[A-Z]*" -maxdepth 1); do
 24   if $(test -d ${DIR}); then
 25     echo $(basename ${DIR});
 26     cd $(basename ${DIR});
 27 
 28     for fname in $(find . -name "*.DAT"); do
 29       echo $(basename $fname);
 30       calType=$(grep 'Level_Unit' $fname | sed -e 's/.*=\([A-Z]\)/\1/');
 31       echo $(basename $calType);
 32         if [ "$calType" == FPL ]
 33         then
 34           echo "This is a keeper " $calType;
 35         fi
 36     done
 37     cd ../
 38 
 39   fi;
 40 
 41 done
```

I am dumping the output on my terminal and here is what I see...

```
sumit$ ./harp_phaseI_calfilenames.sh 
+ rm harp_Phase1_calnames1.txt
+ touch harp_Phase1_calnames1.txt
+ calTest=FPL
++ find . -name 'H[A-Z]*' -maxdepth 1
+ for DIR in '$(find . -name "H[A-Z]*" -maxdepth 1)'
++ test -d ./HALAF032
++ basename ./HALAF032
+ echo HALAF032
HALAF032
++ basename ./HALAF032
+ cd HALAF032
++ find . -name '*.DAT'
+ for fname in '$(find . -name "*.DAT")'
++ basename ./08E21D00.DAT
+ echo 08E21D00.DAT
08E21D00.DAT
++ grep Level_Unit ./08E21D00.DAT
++ sed -e 's/.*=\([A-Z]\)/\1/'
+ calType=$'V\r'
++ basename $'V\r'
+ echo $'V\r'
V
+ '[' $'V\r' == FPL ']'
+ for fname in '$(find . -name "*.DAT")'
```

I banged my head against this for a while and am not getting why there is a dollar sign in "calType=$'V\r'" six lines from the bottom of the output. Then the main question is why the if statement is not being evaluated... " '[' $'V\r' == FPL ']'" on the second line from the bottom. I recognize that the instance I have supplied does not match the string against the variable. But the same thing happens when $calType is "FPL\r".

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Sumit

Comment: There are numerous problems with your code. Run it through shellcheck.net to fix the obvious ones.

Comment: Your file contains DOS style line terminators, causing your string to have a trailing carriage return (`\r`). You can pipe the string through `tr -d '\r'` to strip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you ask about seems to be related to this statement:

```
... | sed -e 's/.*=\([A-Z]\)/\1/'
```

What this will do is, for example given input `x=FPLjunk`, it will output `FPLjunk`.
My rough guess is that you want to keep capital letters and chop off whatever else is left at the end of the line.
Here's one way to achieve that:

```
... | sed -e 's/.*=\([A-Z][A-Z]*\).*/\1/'
```

There are other troubling issues with the script as well.
I fixed many that stand out,
but not everything.
This is equivalent but more optimal and safer,
I suggest to study the difference with your original:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for DIR in "H[A-Z]*"/; do
    echo $(basename "${DIR}")

    for fname in $(find "$DIR" -name "*.DAT"); do
        echo $(basename "$fname")
        calType=$(grep 'Level_Unit' "$fname" | sed -e 's/.*=\([A-Z][A-Z]*\).*/\1/')
        echo $(basename "$calType")
        if [ "$calType" = FPL ]
        then
            echo "This is a keeper " $calType
        fi
    done
done
```

Can the `*.DAT` files be in nested sub-directories?
If not, it would be good to get rid of the `find` command there completely,
and do as I did for the outer loop.

In fact,
if all those `echo`s and `basename`s are not terribly important to you,
and the `*.DAT` files are not in nested directories,
then the entire script could be reduced to just this one-liner:

```
find "H[A-Z]*/" -type f -name "*.DAT" -exec grep Level_Unit + | sed -ne 's/^.*=FPL[^A-Z]*$/This is a keeper FPL/p'
```

Comment: Thank you all. I have been remiss in closing the loop. This ended up being the beginning of using and learning bash. Pretty much all the answers worked as expected. Cleaning up the sed portion of the operation was perhaps most critical.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dos2unix to convert the files to unix format before processing them all.